# How to call asyn function inside for loop Node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I want to call `async.parellel([],function(){})` inside a for loop. When i tried the for loop completes execution before the async function execution.How to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot solve the problem, for it is not a problem, it is how async functions work.

If you start a bunch of async functions during the loop, the latter executes as a whole and puts the formers on the loop to be executed once it releases the control of the flow.

Because of that, you'll see probably the function containing the loop terminates before the async functions start.

The usual approach to give a response to the caller once all the async functions have terminated is by using a callback function as a parameter of the one that contains the root, thus nicely handle the async ones and invoke the callback once all of them have returned.

Comment: i tried the callback concept but i want to call another function after for loop so that time the function inside the for loop is not completed so how to solve this.

Comment: You can either define a function within the one containing the loop that is invoked once all the sync once are terminated and thus invokes the callback, or define a function out of the one containing the loop and bind the callback to it (see *bind* method of a function object), then use it as your callback. There is almost no limit once you start chaining functions in JavaScript and there is a plenty of different solutions. Anyway, this looks to me as another problem, so it would be better if you open another question.

Comment: If you want to call async operation for each item in loop you can use async.each instead of for and execute async.parallel for each item.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Yelizaveta Gagarina.

You can do some stuff like that if you want to work with your for loop:

```
var fns = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  fns.push(function(callback){
     // do stuff here and call your callback with or without error
     callback(null, stuff); // no err in this example
  });
}

async.parallel(fns, function(err, stuff){
    if(err) return cb(err); // in this example err is null
    // do stuff, call next middleware if you are in this case
    next();
});
```

There is also async.series if you want to execute some functions 1 per 1.
Hope this helps you.

Comment: Is the value of `i` can be used in the array of function?

Comment: If you use the i parameter it ll create functions that uses i. Thus your i would be equal to 9 at the end of the loop.
This means that if you just create functions that returns i, you ll have 9 functions that returns the number 9:
`
var fns = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
  fns.push(function(callback){
     return i;
     callback(null, stuff); // no err in this example
  });
}`

Comment: as you say above is the 9 functions return the same value 9 or the value from 0 to 9?

Comment: in the above example, you will have this in the fns array :
`[ [Function],  [Function],  [Function],  [Function],  [Function],  [Function],  [Function],  [Function],  [Function] ]
If you inspect the function they all be the same:
fns[0].toString()
=>'function (callback){ return i; callback(null, stuff); }'

Since i equals 9 at the end of the loop, you ll get 9 times the value of i

Comment: so how can i get the value of `i` inside the function?

Comment: I don't really know what  you are trying to do. You should maybe open a new question as  skypjack  suggested because we are dealing with something else than your original question.

What you can do is something 'weird' like that:

var fns = [];
var async = require('async');
var i = 0; 
var a = 0;`
for (i; i < 9; i++) {
  fns.push(function(callback){
    a++;
     callback(null, a);
  });
}

async.series(fns, function(err, stuff){
    if(err) return cb(err);
    console.log(err, stuff)
});